# How to Add the “Select All” option after long tapping a UITextView in xamarin.ios?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

How to Add the “Select All” option after long tapping a UITextView in xamarin.ios. Its only show Copy, Look Up, Share...
but we want "select all" option without Editable mode.

Please help/guide to solve this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the button "select all " will appear after long tapping .
[image]

And if you click the button , the second menu will appear. 
[image]

Comment: We got "select all" option when text in editable mode but we want every time select all option will show.

Comment: add the  following  code in the ViewController                                                public override bool CanPerform(Selector action, NSObject withSender)
        {
            return true;
        }

Comment: public override bool CanPerform(Selector action, NSObject withSender) { return true; }
its worked..thanks